# Why is plotly connecting my line graph from top to bottom?

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to graph the frequency of Tweets containing a certain keyword throughout the month of January.

```
import plotly.express as px
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

jan = df[(df['datetime'] > dt.datetime(2021,1,1)) & (df['datetime'] < dt.datetime(2021,1,31))]['datetime'].dt.date.value_counts()
jan = pd.DataFrame(jan).reset_index().rename(columns={"datetime" : "Tweet volume", "index" : "datetime"})
fig = px.line(jan, x="datetime", y="Tweet volume")
fig.show()
```

However, plotly connects the points on the time series graph from top to bottom rather than left to right

[image: see screenshot]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is the x-axis in date format instead of string format?

Comment: I also tried it after converting to string format and I have the same result.
`jan["Date"] = jan['datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))`

Comment: So, before the x-axis is converted, it is in date format. My earlier comment was to say that the x-axis needs to be in date format.

Answer (score 0):

- it's not clear the structure of your data frame
- below shows getting tweets that contain *stackoverflow python* and generating a line graph of number of tweets every 4 hours
- key to this is *date* column is a date, not string

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=REPLACE_ME)

# Replace with your own search query
query = 'stackoverflow  python -is:retweet'

tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, tweet_fields=['created_at'], max_results=100)

df = pd.DataFrame([{"date":t.created_at, "text":t.text} for t in tweets.data])

px.line(df.set_index("date").resample("240Min").count().reset_index(), x="date", y="text")
```

[image]